# Comments with votes and "best answers"

Tags: comments, voting-system

I would like to make something like question and answers sites. I need votes and best answer on the comments. I've already done from scratch something but I don't like the appearence and I am looking for a ready template.

I found this one [here](https://www.facebook.com/FenixApps?sk=app_129292167221854) but it is on facebook. I just like the template and the way it show the best answer.

I don't want to use something like disqus. I want to store comments on my own database.

Do you know any html&js template for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For ASP.NET, here is an open source project called Stacked:
   https://code.google.com/p/stacked/
2. There is an example of building a star rating system in ASP.NET MVC
   and jQuery which you might use for inspiration or code ideas -
   http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/building-star-rating-system
3. For C# there is an open source project on GitHub (which may no
   longer be active) : https://github.com/ripper234/Stack-Underflow/ 
   It may not be supported any longer
4. Here is a stackoverflow clone that someone built in ASP.NET MVC for
   practice and documented his steps:
   http://ripper234.com/p/open-source-stackoverflow-clone-by-a-n00b-webdev/
5. Here is one for PHP called Question2Answer:
   http://www.question2answer.org/
6. Another for PHP called Qwench :
   http://anantgarg.com/2009/12/09/php-stackoverflow-clone/
7. And here is one for PHP ZendFramework: 
   http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpancake/
8. If using wordpress, there is a plugin called Q&A:
   http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/qa-wordpress-questions-and-answers-plugin/
9. For Drupal, following this tutorial called 'building a stack
   overflow clone with Drupal' :
   http://engineeredweb.com/blog/09/11/building-stack-overflow-clone-drupal-part-1/
   Drupal also has an answers module: http://drupal.org/project/answers
10. For Java there is AnswerHub: http://answerhub.com/
11. And for Javascript: https://github.com/fuadmuhammad/kerjakelompok/